# How do you say "sharp objects" in Spanish?

Tags: vocabulario, definiciones, significado

I was watching Airport Security Colombia, and sharp objects were mentioned (I know that because of the subtitles).
They said something like "cortopozantes", but I can't find anything like that on Google.

Comment: *objetos afilados* is widely used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word you heard is *[cortopunzante](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=cortopunzante)* and is used in some South American countries. There is also the word *[punzocortante](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UgtD4Tc)*, which is mostly used in Central American countries and Mexico, as reflected by the official RAE dictionary.

In Spain, the [Iberia](http://www.iberia.com/es/equipajes/articulos-peligrosos/) site lists:

> Armas u objetos punzantes o con aristas

(arms, sharp pointed objects or with edges).

And [AirEuropa](https://www.aireuropa.com/es/vuelos/seguridad#objetos-prohibidos):

> Objetos Punzantes o Cortantes

(sharp pointed or cutting objects).

Note that these are more or less technical terms used in legal, medical, or police jargon. A general term for *sharp object* would be:

> Objeto con filo

Answer (score 3):

Se dice objetos punzocortantes.

Palabra compuesta. Punzante es *pricking*. Cortante es *cutting*. Al combinarse las palabras se convierte en punzocortante.

Answer (score 1):

You could also say "objetos filosos" for sharp objects.